# How to assign CLOB variable data to Varchar2 column

Tags: sql, oracle

How to insert a data from table1 column1 which is having a CLOB datatype with length 4708 chars into table2 column2 with varchar2(4000)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 4708 into 4000 won't go. So you'll need to trim it.

```
insert into table2 (column2)
select dbms_lob.substr( column1, 4000, 1 )
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle < 12 there are no other option, you have to trim clob to 4000 as @APC said.

In oracle 12.++ you can `use extended data type`. And change max length limit of varchar from 4000 to 32767. Switching from `standard` to `extended` is one-way operation. [max_string_size](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/extended-data-types-12cR1).

After this you do simple insert from one table to another.